# Node.js Realm not working on Windows 7

Tags: node.js, realm

I followed realm.io tutorial(https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#getting-started), and, in OSX, it works good.

When executing the same program from Windows 7, I receive the following error:

```
D:\offline-ticketing-workspace\realm-base-test>node app
module.js:602
  return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
             ^

Error: The specified procedure could not be found.
\\?\D:\offline-ticketing-workspace\realm-base-test\node_modules\realm\compiled\node-v57_win32_x64\realm.node
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:602:18)
at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\offline-ticketing-workspace\realm-base-test\node_modules\realm\lib\index.js:94:28)
at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
```

### Environment

- windows 7
- nodejs 8.4.0
- realm 1.10.3

Any ideas to what the issue might be?

Comment: You most likely need to use `v6.11.2 LTS Recommended For Most Users` instead of `v8.4.0 Current Latest Features` for NodeJS version

Comment: I tried on node v.6.11.2, but same error. thx

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Realm requires Windows 8.1 or later.

Comment: That's a bummer. Electron does support 7, that means we will probably have to switch our application to SQLite to avoid platform limitations. Any plans to support Windows 7?

Comment: No plan for Windows 7 support. Microsoft ended mainstream support in 2015 and extended support in 2020.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Still does not seem that end users care about it much though: https://gs.statcounter.com/os-version-market-share/windows/desktop/worldwide Windows 7 is still holds significant share of the computers.